# How to create a method for a function?

Tags: javascript

I wish I would create something that will help me to get the last item from an array like this

```
$$("div", list).getLastItem()
```

my function is:

```
const $$ = (selector, parent = document) => {
  x = parent.querySelectorAll(selector);
  x = Array.prototype.slice.call(x);
  return x;
}
```

I was thinking of how to do it, but I'm unable to figure it out, I've tried to do it like this:

```
$$.prototype.getLastItem = ()=>{
return this.slice(-1)[0];
}
```

but it's giving an error:
**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'getLastItem' of undefined**

1-How to implement this?

2-Why my code is not working?

Comment: Are you using jquery or just a plain javascript?

Comment: Vanilla Javascript

Comment: You're returning an Array, so you'd need to put it on `Array.prototype`, not `Function.prototype`.

Comment: ...and by the way, your function can just be `return  Array.from(parent.querySelectorAll(selector));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return an instance of a class which has a `getLastItem` method:

```js
class Dollar {
  constructor(selector, parent = document) {
    this.elements = [...parent.querySelectorAll(selector)];
  }
  getLastItem() {
    return this.elements.slice(-1)[0];
  }
}
const $$ = (...args) => new Dollar(...args);

console.log($$('.something').getLastItem());
```

```html
<div class='something'>something</div>
<div class='something'>something else</div>
```

To access the `n`th element, reference the instance's `.elements[n]` property.

If you also want to be able to access the underlying elements without going through `.elements`, assign to numeric properties in the constructor:

```js
class Dollar {
  constructor(selector, parent = document) {
    this.elements = [...parent.querySelectorAll(selector)];
    Object.assign(this, this.elements);
  }
  getLastItem() {
    return this.elements.slice(-1)[0];
  }
}
const $$ = (...args) => new Dollar(...args);

const somethings = $$('.something');
console.log(somethings[0]);
console.log(somethings.getLastItem());
```

```html
<div class='something'>something</div>
<div class='something'>something else</div>
```

Comment: Thanks your code is amazing.
code you please explain this line






    Object.assign(this, this.elements);

Comment: That puts the numeric-indexed properties from the `.elements` array onto the instance - eg, it means that `$$(...).elements[0]` can be accessed by doing `$$(...)[0]`

Answer (score 0):

`getLastItem` should be bound to the prototype of `Array`:

```js
Array.prototype.getLastItem = function () { ... }
```

Comment: Do you think that this is a good implementation? because I've heard many times that it's not good to change anything inside the prototypes of the built-in javascript methods and functions

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you just want to get the last item or require creating a method for a function.

If you just want to get the last item, can't you just do:

```
const lastItem = $$('div').slice(-1)[0];
```

That seems to get the last div just fine...

Answer (score 0):

You can simply move function `getLastItem` inside `$$` and assign it to `x` as `x.getLastItem`, use `return x.slice(-1)[0]` and return `x`. It will work.

Try it below.

```js
const $$ = (selector, parent = document) => {  
  let x = parent.querySelectorAll(selector);
  x = Array.prototype.slice.call(x);
  x.getLastItem = () => {
    return x.slice(-1)[0];
  }
  return x;
}

console.log($$("div").getLastItem());
console.log($$("div")[0]);
```

```html
<div id='test'></div>
```

Comment: could you please explain what this line is doing return this;

Comment: In my previous code `this` will return `window` object as you are working with `arrow function`. So `getLastItem` will be bind to `window` when you call `$$(...)`. I feel it is better to bind `getLastItem` to specific object rather than `window` so I updated the code and bind it to `x` and return `x`. Now you can also use `$$("div")[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve what you expected right from your current solution with a some changes

- use `function` to access the `this` context
- use *New-Agnostic Constructor Pattern* (as described in David Herman’s Effective JavaScript) to construct object without the need of using `new`
- return the instance itself (`return this`) to use further defined method

```js
function $$(selector, parent = document) {
  if (!(this instanceof $$)) {
    return new $$(selector, parent);
  }

  const x = parent.querySelectorAll(selector);
  this.selected = Array.prototype.slice.call(x);
  return this;
}

$$.prototype.getLastItem = function() {
  return this.selected.slice(-1)[0];
}

console.log($$("div").getLastItem())
```

```html
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
<div>5</div>
```